# Different commands to undo changes in a local file

Tags: git

What is the difference between the following commands to undo changes in a local file?

```
git checkout HEAD <file>

git reset <file>

git checkout -- <file>
```

Comment: For `reset` vs `checkout`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout

For `checkout` w/ vs w/o `HEAD`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54680870/4636715

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "git reset" and "git checkout"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+checkout+reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) we can see that 1. and 3. are the same. Also both the working tree and the index is updated:

> git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​
>
> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents [..] in the <tree-ish> (most often a commit). When a <tree-ish> is given, the paths that match the <pathspec> are updated both in the index and in the working tree.

From [git-reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset), we see that only the index is updated:

> git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] …​
>
> [...] copy entries from <tree-ish> to the index.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So ```git reset``` will just unstage the file, but ```git checkout``` will discard changes in the working directory. Also, ```--``` and ```HEAD``` are equivalent.